# HTML does not display my Java Applet with a JLabel

Tags: java, html, applet, jlabel

When I execute the HTML file associated with my applet, nothing is drawn and the screen is empty. Why does this happen?  How do I add a String into the Applet?

Source code for the Java Applet:

```java
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Displaytext extends JApplet {
//Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
                String answer = telnet.request();
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(answer);
                add(lbl);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML code which embeds your applet, and list which browser you are using.

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: <HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
<APPLET CODE="m2mcom.web.Displaytext.class" WIDTH="1000" HEIGHT="800">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>