# Java Applet SwingUtilities empty screen

Tags: java, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML does not display my Java Applet with a JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524480/html-does-not-display-my-java-applet-with-a-jlabel)

I have the next code source for a Java Applet:

```
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Displaytext extends JApplet {
//Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
                String answer = telnet.request();
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(answer);
                add(lbl);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
}
```

The telnet request is made in the AutomatedTelnetClient class and once the response is obtained the session is also closed. 
When I execute the .html file nothing is drawn and the screen is empty. Anyone knows why does it act like does. Is there other way to add a string into the Applet? Could it be that the problem is the inovkeAndWait from SwingUtilities?

This is the HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
<APPLET CODE="m2mcom.web.Displaytext.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

try NOT run the

```
AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
```

in a SwingUtilities thread. b/c the telnet request is very likely asynchronous call.
try running the above code directly without using a thread and see what you get.

---UPDATE---

another issue could be the last line in my code below which add the label to your applet contentPane component. this might be the problem.

If these two fixes don't work then it very likely you have a problem in your *AutomatedTelnetClient* class logic.

```
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Displaytext extends JApplet {
//Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
    try {

                AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
                String answer = telnet.request();
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(answer);
                getContentPane().add(lbl);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: But I must initialize somehow the AutomatedTelnetClient telnet to be able to call the request method later

Comment: i have updated my answer with code you can try. just run the code without using another thread and only the main applet init thread. see the code above and let me know if that fixes your problem.note the last two line which add the lable to your applet. this might be the problem. you can add these two lines in your current code and see if it works.

Comment: I get the error 'cannot find symbol' for pack();

Comment: You can't `pack()` an applet, pretty much by definition. Size is defined in the html.